# Find array wise ids from comma separated ids in mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

i have one table which contains multiple comma separated ids with multiple fields like:

[image]

i need some proid which i have already pass using array in mysql

```
proid = array([0]=>51,[1]=>54,[2]=>8)
```

i want that rows which contains 51,54 & 8 `proid` from the table field which is in comma separate proids

```
51,52,53,54,2,3,4,5,8,9,11,55,13,14,15,16,17,18,1,...
```

here i try `FIND_IN_SET` but not work properly in select query, can see below

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_request` WHERE FIND_IN_SET('51,54,8', `proid`) > 0
```

can anyone help me out please,

thanks in advance

Comment: did you tried : SELECT * FROM `tbl_request` WHERE FIND_IN_SET('51,54,8', `proid`)

Comment: SELECT FIND_IN_SET('51', '51,54,8') or FIND_IN_SET('54', '51,54,8') or FIND_IN_SET('8', '51,54,8');

Comment: @Amit yes i tried but, not working                                                        select * from tbl_request where find_in_set('51',proid) <> 0 for single proid , it will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIND_IN_SET() function take first parameter as a complete string and compare it with the second parameters.
If you pass 51 as first param then SQL will return you the results. But you try for '51,8' then it will treat it as a one string not two, and it will search for complete '51,8'. 
So you need to as Jothi mentioned in comments

```
SELECT FIND_IN_SET('51', `proid`) > 0 or FIND_IN_SET('54', `proid`) > 0 or FIND_IN_SET('8', `proid`) > 0;
```

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set,
http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-find_in_set-function.php

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `tbl_request` WHERE ';
$items = array(51,54,8);
foreach($items as $item){
    $where[] = "FIND_IN_SET('$item', `proid`) > 0";
}
if(is_array($where)){
    $sql.= implode(' OR ', $where);
}else{
    $sql.= '1';
}
```

Comment: dear @PARAG , but i have multiple data in array and how to find out from string, i am very confuse

Comment: so you you means i have to use loop from array data in after where clause .right???

Answer (score 0):

**FIND_IN_SET()** only finds the position of the first argument.

You may try

```
SELECT
 *
FROM tbl_request
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('51', proid)
   OR FIND_IN_SET('54', proid)
   OR FIND_IN_SET('8', proid);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like below:

```
$proid = array(0=>51,1=>54,2=>8);

$cond_array = array() ;

foreach($proid as $val){
    $cond_array[] = "FIND_IN_SET($val, `proid`) > 0";
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_request` WHERE ".implode(' OR ', $cond_array);

echo $sql;
```

output :

```
SELECT SELECT * FROM `tbl_request` WHERE FIND_IN_SET(51, `proid`) > 0 OR FIND_IN_SET(54, `proid`) > 0 OR FIND_IN_SET(8, `proid`) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
            <?php

        $proid = array(51,54,8);


        $concat='';

        foreach($proid as $row)
        {
          if(empty($concat))
          {
              $concat.=" FIND_IN_SET('$row', proid) >0";

          }
          else
          {

           $concat.=" or FIND_IN_SET('$row', proid) >0";
          }


        }

        echo "SELECT * FROM tbl_request WHERE ".$concat

        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Guys for multiple fields selection i use this code and it working fine

```
$proids='';
        foreach($_POST["product"] as $row_product)
        {
          if(empty($proids))
          {
              $proids.=" FIND_IN_SET('$row_product', `proid`) >0";
          }
          else
          {
            $proids.=" OR FIND_IN_SET('$row_product', `proid`) >0";
          }
        }

        $disidreport='';
        foreach($_POST["distributor"] as $row_distributor)
        {
          if(empty($disidreport))
          {
              $disidreport.=" FIND_IN_SET('$row_distributor', `disidreport`) >0";
          }
          else
          {
            $disidreport.=" OR FIND_IN_SET('$row_distributor', `disidreport`) >0";
          }
        }

        echo $select_req = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_request` WHERE (".$disidreport.") AND (".$proids.")";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM course where ';
$items = array(49,50,52);
foreach($items as $item){
    $where[] = "FIND_IN_SET(cid,'$item') > 0";
}
if(is_array($where)){
    $sql.= implode(' OR ', $where);

}else{
    $sql.= '1';

}
$statement = $dbo->prepare($sql);

$statement->execute();

$result = $statement->fetchAll();

  foreach($result as $row)
     {
      echo $sid=$row["cid"]."      ";
      echo $name = $row["cname"]."<br>";
     }
}
```

**It will Work Like Charm Modified in the above statement I am not getting the result. but after changing in FIND_IN_SET I will get all the data.**

[image]

That's statement right I am not telling that is wrong but Mistake is in **FIND_IN_SET function of SQL**. You can see in the picture what query will help me to get the database.